# J2ME Camera and Sound Recorder Access On A Windows Mobile

Tags: java-me, windows-mobile, camera, audio-recording, mmapi

I'm currently involved in a research project that requires me to access a Windows Mobile Camera and sound recorder with J2ME to, well take pictures and record sound... the phone has to be a windows mobile for some reason that has nothing to do with me and the software has to be written in Java, also not my decision.

So I need to try and find a phone that supports this (if one exists) so I'd like to know if anyone has found one?

Thank You For Your Help.

(Note the phone supporting MMAPI (JSR 135) does not imply that you can use the camera and sound recorder, our current phone has this and has not access).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you have any Windows Mobile 6.x device, please try to use JVM build for Windows Mobile from Sun Microsystems => http://blogs.oracle.com/javamesdk/entry/jvm_for_windows_mobile

Or, you can buy LG Monaco (WM 6.5) from AT&T network. It has Java ME with MMAPI camera support. Also, LG Incite (WM 6.1) have MMAPI camera support.

As I know, recent HTC WM device with Java ME also support MMAPI camera features.

Good luck.